# Running Django Commands on a different server

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, server, amazon-rds

Right now I have a django website. I manage to programmatically populate the database using django commands and everything works fine.
I now want to have a dedicated server for populating the database programmatically but I do not want to give up using django commands as thei are very powerful in my opinion.

I am using aws elastic beanstalk and an rds db instance, so I know that I could simply create my scripts (the ones I use to populate the db) in pure python, but I am wondering if there is a nice way to do the same using Django.

I thought of simply setting up a new Django project that connects to the same RDS database, but this would mean that I need to copy all the models/settings every time a make a change to my main website... I did not really seem ideal.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm a little unclear what you're asking. Do you mean you want to set up a parallel web server that shares the same models as the primary but runs different apps?

Comment: Because if so then I think you might do better to just set up some manage.py commands and run them on a local machine, the same way you already programmatically populated the database.

Comment: My goal is to have a dedicated server that populates the database. The apps will be run by the stuff that I already have, but I want to divide the 2 things as for now the commands that populate the db are inside the management/commands/ folder in one of my apps. Also, I am wondering if these commands that I have will be run twice when elastic beanstalk will fire up new instance.

Comment: Personally, I would probably use the same project code for both servers, but use environment variables to differentiate between the two. Then in settings.py, enable/disable certain apps based on the envvars, or if that's too coarse, then enable/disable URLs so that your dedicated database server isn't used for a web server, and your web server isn't used for populating the database. Creating a new project seems extremely unnecessary and a huge headache to maintain, like you said.

Comment: @vittoriosomaschini | Maybe `fabfile (fabric file)` is what you want, [link](http://www.fabfile.org)